# Is Nagash younger than Thutep?

Tags: warhammer-fantasy

I am reading *Rise of Nagash* by Mike Lee.

In *The Elixir of Life* we learn about Nagash's brother, Thutep:

> It was not so much the act of removing Thutep that was so abhorrent, for the young king had been widely viewed as foolish and naive, but the fact that Nagash had violated the covenant of the gods by claiming the crown. As **firstborn**, his life belonged to the gods, and thus he had set a dangerous precedent that the other kings could not abide.

In *New Beginnings*, Thutep's ghost haunts Nagash:

> *Usurpation is not a right, brother.*
>
> Thutep stood at the crest of the ridge, his face turned towards the moon hanging low overhead. His **older** brother seemed damnably at peace, staring up at Neru's beaming face.

Bold emphasis is mine in both quotes.

My question is, **which of the brothers is eldest? Or is New Beginnings a mistake on the author's part?**

---

P.S I believe Nagash is the eldest, as his usurpation is one of the reasons why the other kings rise up against him.

Comment: Sounds like a typo to me

Comment: Unfortunately the Black Library does not scrutinize what they publish for canon and continuity as they should... If anything regarding these brothers in stated in a corresponding war scroll that is what I would take as canon.

Comment: I think that book 3 of _Rise of Nagash_ wasn't well proof read. I just noticed they say the siege of Mahrak took 10 years, but it actually took 4...